# NameError: name 'my_part_outline

Tags: python

i am using cnc25d software on my raspberry pi ,i have been tried the code below

```
# import the FreeCAD library
from cnc25d import cnc25d_api
cnc25d_api.importing_freecad()
import Part
from FreeCAD import Base

# use the cnc_cut_outline function
my_polygon = [
  [  0,  0,    5],
  [ 40,  0,    5],
  [ 40, 40,    5],
  [  0, 40,    5]]
my_part_face = Part.Face(Part.Wire(cnc25d_api.cnc_cut_outline(my_part_outline).Edges))
my_part_solid = my_part_face.extrude(Base.Vector(0,0,20))

# use the place_plank function
my_part_a = cnc25d_api.place_plank(my_part_solid.copy(), 40, 40, 20, 'i', 'xz', 0, 0, 0)

# export your design as DXF
cnc25d_api.export_to_dxf(my_part_solid, Base.Vector(0,0,1), 1.0, "my_part.dxf")
xy_slice_list = [ 0.1+4*i for i in range(9) ]
xz_slice_list = [ 0.1+4*i for i in range(9) ]
yz_slice_list = [ 0.1+2*i for i in range(9) ]
cnc25d_api.export_xyz_to_dxf(my_part_solid, 40, 40, 20, xy_slice_list, xz_slice_list, yz_slice_list, "my_part_scanned.dxf")
```

but i get this error

> NameError: name 'my_part_outline' is not defined

so, i need some help please

Comment: `my_part_face = Part.Face(Part.Wire(cnc25d_api.cnc_cut_outline(my_part_outline).Edges))` you called `my_part_outline` without defining it...

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use a variable **my_part_outline** to send to a function.  The variable does not have a value at this point.  In fact, it doesn't appear anywhere else in your posted code.  How is the Python run-time system supposed to know the value to send to function **cnc_cut_outline**?

As you're learning, I'm sure, confusing the computer is *not* an effective way to get the results you want.  :-)

Comment: hhh, you are right i am still learning ,thank u for your note